# Make months on x-axis clickable on chart.js line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm creating [a line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj09S.png) with chart.js. My x-axis is time-based and displays months.
Each "month column" should be clickable/selectable, but I cannot find a way to manage this. Methods like `getElementAtEvent()` return data, so I can find out which month is selected. But they only work if the user clicks right on a point, and not anywhere in the "column".

How can I do that? Or is there already a plugin for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this working using an undocumented time scale prototype method called `.getValueForPixel()`, which returns the scale value of the scale region that was clicked.

This method returns a moment object that was used to generate the scale tick label, so you can use the same format string configured for your time scale when displaying this value (if you want them to be visually equal).  I coupled this with the generic [`onClick` option config property](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration) for a pretty simple approach for what you are wanting to do.

Here is how to do it.  In your `options` object, add an `onClick` property using this function.

```
onClick: function(e) {
  var xLabel = this.scales['x-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(e.x);
  console.log(xLabel.format('MMM YYYY'));
  alert("clicked x-axis area: " + xLabel.format('MMM YYYY'));
},
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/gmdGGw) to see it in action.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as intended. I [updated your codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmdxyO), made it much shorter and used a "real" time x-axis (using [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment)). Here, only two points exist. So anywhere you click, you get index 0 or 1. But I'd like to get the months (format maybe YYYY-MM), even if they're not holding data, when I click on their columns.

Comment: I'll take a look.  In the future, its always best to post your specific chart.js config so it can be used to derive an question.  It wasn't clear in your answer you were using a time scale.

Comment: @DoeTheFourth Updated the answer for a solution that works with the time scale.

Comment: Great! But instead of using `e.x` `e.offsetX` must be used, as it measures from the target node and not the page. Thank you very much!

Comment: how do I make it so that it doesn't respond to a click anywhere on the canvas?  What if I only want this click to respond to the axis label click?