# event click only x-axis label chartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

It is possible to retrieve the click event only on label of the x-axis in chartJS?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pns0l.png)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make months on x-axis clickable on chart.js line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046818/make-months-on-x-axis-clickable-on-chart-js-line-chart)

Comment: In that example the click event is on the whole graph and not only on the x axis label...

Answer (score 0):

No, since chart.js V3 the click event is limited to the chart area only so you will need to add your own click listener to the canvas.

In this click listener you can then use the `getValueForPixel` to get the X label